# Use native promise in protractor

Tags: typescript, protractor

Is there way to use protractor `filter` which accepts a function that returns protractor's own Promise type, with my own function that returns native Promise?

```
const myFilter = async(e: ElementFinder): Promise<boolean> => {
...
}
myElements.filter(myFilter)
```

This raises TypeScript compilation error

> TS2345:Argument of type '(e: ElementFinder) => >Promise' is not assignable to parameter of type '(element: >ElementFinder, index?: number) => boolean | Promise'.
>    Type 'Promise' is not assignable to type 'boolean | Promise'.
>      Type 'Promise' is not assignable to type 'promise.Promise'.
>        Property 'cancel' is missing in type 'Promise'.

BTW, I cannot create protractor's Promise myself, because of deprecaion (https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2969)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, If this is still relevant, I got to working with tests again and this time I found a solution right away.

These helpers open the bridge between `protractor.promise.Promise` and native `Promise`.

```js
const toNativePromise = <T = void>(p: protractor.promise.Promise<T>): Promise<T> => { 
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        p.then(res).catch(rej)
    })
}
```

```js
const toProtractorPromise = <T = void>(native_promise: Promise<T>): protractor.promise.Promise<T> => {
    const deferred = protractor.promise.defer<T>();
    const protractorPromise = deferred.promise;
    native_promise.then(deferred.fulfill).catch(deferred.reject)
    return protractorPromise
}
```

Anyways, For solving your initial problem, you can write something like this:

```
const myFilter = async(e: ElementFinder): Promise<boolean> => { ... }
const myFilterForProtractor = (e) => toProtractorPromise(myFilter(e))
```